# How to make a Request over NFC Reader ACR122u when auto polling is disabled

Tags: python, nfc, pyscard

Is there a solution to send a direct command to the reader to search for    available cards even if auto polling is disabled?

I want to read from an RFID Chip over the ACR122U NFC reader. I tried the nfcpy lib but every time when I read the tag the script interrupts. So I tried the pyscard lib, which can read and write on the tag but it polls the whole time and the led is red until a tag is near enough to read then it turns green. In the nfcpy lib the led was the whole time off. I can send the command in pyscard to disable the auto polling and so the led problem but know the reader can't find the tag even if I send a direct command to the reader to read all near cards.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time and visit [SO Asking Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and must read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the same.